# PWAs: Enterprise deployment via MDM solutions

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps

I think especially for enterprise applications with many different mobile devices and OSs PWAs could be very interesting. However, I wondered if there already is a way to easily deploy enterprise PWAs via a mobile device management solution? Telling all users to go to a specific website and click on the "Add to homescreen" banner seems inconvenient to me. On iOS with Safari the user even has to manually add a shortcut to the home screen.

- Android: Google Chrome already generates Web APKs. Maybe these could be extended to allow such deployment scenarios. Are such features planned for the future?
- iOS: Does this already work when simply adding a shortcut to the specific URL of the PWA to the homescreen via a MDM solution?

Comment: Interesting that this idea doesn't seem to have gone anywhere. I once tried out the MaaS360 web app distribution method: https://ibm.co/2RMObOX
That didn't work out though. Another idea for Android would be to build the TWA that's used on the Play Store and distribute that: https://firt.dev/pwa-playstore.